# Graph client access

Tags: graph, graphserviceclient

im trying to get access to graph account in windows service app.
this is my code.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(ObjectId)
.WithClientId(clientId)
.WithTenantId(TenantID)
.WithClientName(UserName)
.WithClientSecret(SecretValue)
.Build();

    var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientApplication);
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    IUserRequestBuilder client = graphClient.Users[clientId];


    var messages = await client.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
    .Request()
    .Expand("attachments")
    .GetAsync();

    foreach (var mssg in messages)
    {//do my things}
```

in the "await client.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages" line i get
Status Code: NotFound
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: User not found

thanks for any answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be related to this line

```
IUserRequestBuilder client = graphClient.Users[clientId];
```

instead of `clientId` you need to use user principal name (usually same as mail address) or user id which is not the same as `clientId`.

```
IUserRequestBuilder client = graphClient.Users["john.doe@foo.com"];
```